# Some font not displaying in web

Tags: php, mysql, webfonts

I wrote some text in my Android app using google input keyboard. it displaying properly in android app. But in web it display as

```
\u0D2E\u0D32\u0D2F\u0D3E\u0D33\u0D02 \uD83D\uDE1B
```

How to display it properly in web using php ?

Comment: Which encoding are you using for your PHP files which encoding is the web server using?

Comment: tried with mb_convert_encoding , but no use

Comment: if you are using Android WebView to insert into your website so you should use 
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
also in your website using the same meta tag which make the browser reading the language with UTf-8
also I think if you stored the text in the database be sure that the database already set to use utf-8